# Loading a UIWebView from a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

I've come to a part of my code where I'm a bit stumped, what I'm basically trying to do is to load once you tap for example Google in the UITableView, it will then load Google from a separate view controller that is a UIWebView. I've coded what I think is right although when I tap on Google, nothing happens. I'm not getting any errors, the app runs fine it's just as I said once you tap the selected field it doesn't lead anywhere & before you say anything I did remember to import the UIWebView controller into my first view controllers .m file.

This is my first view controller .h

```
@interface YoMaFifthViewController : UITableViewController

{

NSArray *data, *sites;
} 


@end
```

This is my first view controller .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Website", @"Developer", nil];
sites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         @"https://www.google.co.uk/",
         @"https://www.google.co.uk/",
         nil];
```

`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

`

```
 // Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
```

`

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
YoMaWebsiteViewController *wvc = [[YoMaWebsiteViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"YoMaWebsiteViewController" bundle:nil];
wvc.site = [sites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];

}
```

This is my UIWebViews .h

`

```
@interface YoMaWebsiteViewController : UIViewController
{

IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

}

@property (retain) NSString *site;


@end
```

& This is the UIWebViews .m

`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.site];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that all your methods are getting hit?  Also, does the view change, but the url is blank?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the url is getting set after the viewDidLoad method is being executed.  Regardless, it's not a bad idea to have the loadURL method in your setter (or some public method to re-load the url and refresh the webview).

```
-(void)setSite:(NSString*)s {
    _site = s;

    if(webview) {
        [self loadURL];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([self.site length] > 0) {
        [self loadURL];
    }
}

-(void)loadURL {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.site];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement what you said into my code although I was getting a host of errors. Here's the WebView View Controllers .m, implement it into there please. Is there any changes that I need to make in my WebView controllers .h, my first view controllers .h & .m or is it just the WebView .m

Comment: I did two things.  First, I broken the load url code into a separate function.  This makes it easy to call from multiple places.  Second, I made a call to loadURL in your site setter.  This will load the passed in url anytime the property gets changed.  What problems were you having before, and what problems are you having now?  Does the view change, but the webview not load the url?

Comment: The view doesn't change at all, I click on the selected field on my TableView and the field highlights itself blue although it doesn't change view, it just stays on the same page here's an image of what happens: - http://i.imgur.com/FiUHFdv.png

Comment: Can you set a break point in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and make sure your code hits this method when a row gets selected?

Comment: I would do that although I have no clue on how to do that!

Comment: Click in the gray area where you want to pause the execution.  It'll allow you to inspect all your in scope variables.  It's pretty FUNdamental to programming.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Comment: I put a breakpoint in where you said and then I ran the simulator, after clicking on table view it keeps highlighting this line of code: - `code`  YoMaWebsiteViewController *wvc = [[YoMaWebsiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YoMaWebsiteViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: It highlights it, because that's where execution is paused.  You can hit the play button in the bottom panel to continue execution.  The fact that it hit your break point means the tap is registering the click correctly and your delegation is setup properly.  Next you need to find out if your view controller and navigation controller is getting initialized correctly.

Comment: I'm really sorry for this, I feel like I'm wasting your time it's just I've never done this before

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. No worries.

Comment: How do I understand if they're being initialized correctly? By doing all of this should this find the problem in my programme?

Comment: Look up how to debug using XCode.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I'll do that now!

Comment: Hi Jeff  I thought I should get back to you because you've been so helpful. I think I'm going to have to abondon this application because I just can't figure it out why it's not working and I don't understand debugging at all, I can't understand how you figure out if something is initialized correctly and I certainly don't understand how to find why my app isn't working the way it should do. Thanks again though!

Comment: No problem.  Maybe try to simplify the program a little by just having a UIWebView and not UITableView.